# Background 100% and scroll problem

Tags: jquery, css, background, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I try to put a background in 100% with the following code:

```
html {
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-color: # f2f2f2;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-image: url (.. / images / background.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top left;
}
```

my problem is that when I scroll the scroll my content is choppy.
I tested everything with image resize script jquery
and doing research I found nothing on the subject,
If I turn off the background at 100%, the scroll is again fluid.
What is my problem?
website: http://www.confederationcreative.ch/dcube/en/store/

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for my vague answer, but I have not experienced any choppiness in Firefox 4, Internet Explorer 9, and Chrome 10.0.648.208.

It helps if you tell is your browser (IE, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, etc.) and your version (IE9, Firefox 4, Chrome 10, Opera 10, etc.).

Also, what OS are you using and what are your computer specs? Not that it matters, but I thought I might ask.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'm running in mac osX and the scroll is not smooth on chrome, in safari and FF it is more smooth, but not as if I disable the background. Chrome is 10.0.648.204, firefox 3.5.18 and safari 5.0.3